# QuickBlox chat, by leaked IntentReceiver of vc908.stickerfactory, unregisterReceiver error

Tags: android, out-of-memory, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am using `Quickblox chat sample`. When I run chat app, there is no error.

But after kill process project, app happens crashes. Because `AnalyticsTaskReceiver` and `UpdatePacksTaskReceiver.`

When I use `vc908.stickerfactory library`, chat activity have warning, that ChatActivity has leaked IntentReceiver `vc908.stickerfactory.o@32b64b7c` which was originally registered here.

Are you missing a call to `unregisterReceiver()?` So I try to find registered receiver but didn't found.

How can I fix this bug?

I use this;
`compile('vc908.stickers:stickerfactory:0.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }'

`public class CustomBuyingChatActivity extends BaseActivity implements KeyboardHandleRelativeLayout.KeyboardSizeChangeListener {

```
private static final String TAG = CustomBuyingChatActivity.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String EXTRA_DIALOG = "dialog";
private final String PROPERTY_SAVE_TO_HISTORY = "save_to_history";

private EditText messageEditText;
private ListView messagesContainer;
private Button sendButton;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ChatAdapter adapter;

private Chat chat;
private QBDialog dialog;
private KeyboardHandleRelativeLayout keyboardHandleLayout;
private View stickersFrame;
private boolean isStickersFrameVisible;
private ImageView stickerButton;
private RelativeLayout container;

private QBSentData receiveSellerData;
private String sellerName;
private QBUser selectedUser;

private ImageView sellerImage;
private TextView goods,sellername, orderprice;
private CircularImageView manphoto;
private Button btnBack;
private String manPhotoUrl, myPhotoUrl;
private SharedPreferences objSharedPref;

public static void start(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buying_chat);

    objSharedPref = Utils.getSharedPreferences(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    receiveSellerData = (QBSentData)extras.getSerializable("senddatatoCustomChat");
    sellerName = receiveSellerData.getSellername();

    sellerImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.seller_photo11);
    goods = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.goodsname11);
    sellername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sellername11);
    orderprice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price11);
    manphoto = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.manphoto11);
    btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnqb_back);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    goods.setText(receiveSellerData.getTitle());
    sellername.setText(receiveSellerData.getSellername());
    orderprice.setText("$ " + receiveSellerData.getId());

    manPhotoUrl = receiveSellerData.getSellerPhoto();
    myPhotoUrl = objSharedPref.getString(Utils.USERPHOTO, "");

    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(sellerImage, receiveSellerData.getImage_url(), R.drawable.no_image, new UrlImageViewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Bitmap loadedBitmap, String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
            if (!loadedFromCache) {
                ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
                scale.setDuration(300);
                scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                imageView.startAnimation(scale);
            }
        }
    });

    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(manphoto, receiveSellerData.getSellerPhoto(), R.drawable.no_image, new UrlImageViewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Bitmap loadedBitmap, String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
            if (!loadedFromCache) {
                ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
                scale.setDuration(300);
                scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
                imageView.startAnimation(scale);
            }
        }
    });
    loadNext();

    ChatService.getInstance().addConnectionListener(chatConnectionListener);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {



    ChatService.getInstance().removeConnectionListener(chatConnectionListener);

    if (!getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromDialog", false)) {

        QBChatService.getInstance().destroy();

    }

    Utils.garbageCollect();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isStickersFrameVisible) {
        setStickersFrameVisible(false);
        stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_insert_emoticon);

    } else {
        try {
            chat.release();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to release chat", e);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();



        finish();
    }
}

private void initViews() {
    messagesContainer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagescontainer11);
    messageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit11);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    TextView companionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.companionLabel11);


    container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container11);
    if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP) {
        TextView meLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meLabel11);
        container.removeView(meLabel);
        container.removeView(companionLabel);
    } else if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PRIVATE) {
        Integer opponentID = ChatService.getInstance().getOpponentIDForPrivateDialog(dialog);
        companionLabel.setText(ChatService.getInstance().getDialogsUsers().get(opponentID).getLogin());
    }

    // Send button
    //
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chatSendButton11);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String messageText = messageEditText.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)) {
                return;
            }
            sendChatMessage(messageText);

        }
    });

    // Stickers
    keyboardHandleLayout = (KeyboardHandleRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sizeNotifierLayout11);
    keyboardHandleLayout.listener = this;
    stickersFrame = findViewById(R.id.frame11);
    stickerButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stickers_button11);

    stickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isStickersFrameVisible) {
                showKeyboard();
                stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_insert_emoticon);
            } else {
                if (keyboardHandleLayout.isKeyboardVisible()) {
                    keyboardHandleLayout.hideKeyboard(CustomBuyingChatActivity.this, new KeyboardHandleRelativeLayout.OnKeyboardHideCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onKeyboardHide() {
                            stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_keyboard);
                            setStickersFrameVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_keyboard);
                    setStickersFrameVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    updateStickersFrameParams();
    StickersFragment stickersFragment = (StickersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame11);
    if (stickersFragment == null) {
        stickersFragment = new StickersFragment.Builder()
                .setStickerPlaceholderColorFilterRes(android.R.color.darker_gray)
                .build();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame11, stickersFragment).commit();
    }
    stickersFragment.setOnStickerSelectedListener(stickerSelectedListener);
    stickersFragment.setOnEmojiBackspaceClickListener(new OnEmojiBackspaceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEmojiBackspaceClicked() {
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(
                    0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
            messageEditText.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });
    setStickersFrameVisible(isStickersFrameVisible);
}

private void showKeyboard() {
    ((InputMethodManager) messageEditText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(messageEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}

private void sendChatMessage(String messageText) {
    QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
    chatMessage.setBody(messageText);
    chatMessage.setProperty(PROPERTY_SAVE_TO_HISTORY, "1");
    chatMessage.setDateSent(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    try {
        chat.sendMessage(chatMessage);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to send a message", e);
    } catch (SmackException sme) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failed to send a message", sme);
    }

    messageEditText.setText("");

    if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PRIVATE) {
        showMessage(chatMessage);
    }
}

private OnStickerSelectedListener stickerSelectedListener = new OnStickerSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStickerSelected(String code) {
        if (StickersManager.isSticker(code)) {
            sendChatMessage(code);

        } else {
            // append emoji to edit
            messageEditText.append(code);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onKeyboardVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
        setStickersFrameVisible(false);
        stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_insert_emoticon);
    } else {
        if (isStickersFrameVisible) {
            stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_keyboard);
        } else {
            stickerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_insert_emoticon);
        }
    }
}

private void setStickersFrameVisible(final boolean isVisible) {
    stickersFrame.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    isStickersFrameVisible = isVisible;
    if (stickersFrame.getHeight() != vc908.stickerfactory.utils.KeyboardUtils.getKeyboardHeight()) {
        updateStickersFrameParams();
    }
    final int padding = isVisible ? vc908.stickerfactory.utils.KeyboardUtils.getKeyboardHeight() : 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        keyboardHandleLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentBottomPadding(padding);
                scrollDown();
            }
        });
    } else {
        setContentBottomPadding(padding);
    }
    scrollDown();
}

private void updateStickersFrameParams() {
    StickersManager.initialize("847b82c49db21ecec88c510e377b452c", this);


    int d = vc908.stickerfactory.utils.KeyboardUtils.getKeyboardHeight();
    stickersFrame.getLayoutParams().height = vc908.stickerfactory.utils.KeyboardUtils.getKeyboardHeight();
}

public void setContentBottomPadding(int padding) {
    container.setPadding(0, 0, 0, padding);
}

private void initChat() {

    if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP) {
```

//            now I don't need GroupChat;

```
        // Join group chat
        //
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //
        joinGroupChat();

    } else if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PRIVATE) {
        Integer opponentID = ChatService.getInstance().getOpponentIDForPrivateDialog(dialog);

        chat = new PrivateChatImpl(CustomBuyingChatActivity.this, opponentID);

        // Load CHat history
        //
        loadChatHistory();
    }
}

private void joinGroupChat() {
    ((GroupChatImpl) chat).joinGroupChat(dialog, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

            // Load Chat history
            //
            loadChatHistory();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List list) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomBuyingChatActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("error when join group chat: " + list.toString()).create().show();
        }
    });
}

private void loadChatHistory() {
    QBRequestGetBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    customObjectRequestBuilder.setPagesLimit(100);
    customObjectRequestBuilder.sortDesc("date_sent");

    QBChatService.getDialogMessages(dialog, customObjectRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBChatMessage>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages, Bundle args) {

            adapter = new ChatAdapter(CustomBuyingChatActivity.this, new ArrayList<QBChatMessage>(), manPhotoUrl, myPhotoUrl);
            messagesContainer.setAdapter(adapter);

            for (int i = messages.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                QBChatMessage msg = messages.get(i);
                showMessage(msg);
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("real", false)){
                sendChatMessage("I want to buy.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            if (!CustomBuyingChatActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomBuyingChatActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("load chat history errors: " + errors).create().show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void showMessage(QBChatMessage message) {
    adapter.add(message);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            scrollDown();
        }
    });
}

private void scrollDown() {
    messagesContainer.setSelection(messagesContainer.getCount() - 1);
}


ConnectionListener chatConnectionListener = new ConnectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {
        Log.i(TAG, "connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection) {
        Log.i(TAG, "authenticated");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        Log.i(TAG, "connectionClosed");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(final Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "connectionClosedOnError: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

        // leave active room
        //
        if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP) {
            CustomBuyingChatActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((GroupChatImpl) chat).leave();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(final int seconds) {
        if (seconds % 5 == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "reconnectingIn: " + seconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        Log.i(TAG, "reconnectionSuccessful");

        // Join active room
        //
        if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP) {
            CustomBuyingChatActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    joinGroupChat();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(final Exception error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "reconnectionFailed: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
};


//
// ApplicationSessionStateCallback
//

@Override
public void onStartSessionRecreation() {

}

@Override
public void onFinishSessionRecreation(final boolean success) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (success) {
                initChat();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void loadNext(){
    getQBPagedRequestBuilder(1);
}

public  void getQBPagedRequestBuilder(int page){
    QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(page);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(50);

    QBUsers.getUsers(pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> result, Bundle params) {
            for (QBUser user : result) {
                if (user.getLogin().equals(sellerName)) {
                    selectedUser = user;
                    break;
                }
            }
            gotoChatRoom();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Log.d("=============", errors.get(0));
            String Error = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); i++){
                Error += errors.get(i) + " ";
            }

            finish();
        }
    });
}

public void gotoChatRoom(){
    List<QBUser> selected = new ArrayList<QBUser>();
    selected.add(selectedUser);
    ChatService.getInstance().addDialogsUsers(selected);

    //Create new dialog
    QBDialog dialogToCreate = new QBDialog();
    dialogToCreate.setName(usersListToChatName());
    dialogToCreate.setType(QBDialogType.PRIVATE);
    dialogToCreate.setOccupantsIds(getUserIds(selectedUser));

    QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager().createDialog(dialogToCreate, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBDialog result, Bundle params) {

            dialog = result;
            initViews();
            if (isSessionActive()) {
                initChat();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            super.onError(errors);
            String Error = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); i++){
                Error += errors.get(i) + " ";
            }

            finish();
        }
    });
}

private String usersListToChatName(){
    return selectedUser.getLogin();
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getUserIds(QBUser user) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ids.add(user.getId());
    return ids;
}`
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Comment: Why you initialize StickersManager at updateStickersFrameParams() ?
You need to do this at your Application onCreate() method.

Comment: Also the actual Stickerpipe library version is 0.7.18

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.In my app, chat is one part of project.
In this condition, where should i have to initialize Stickermanager?
Now I kill crash of exception and run my project.Please answer.

Comment: @AlexShevchenko
First, you need to initialize StickersManager at your Application onCreate() method. If your app still crashing - update library version to 0.7.18. Then you need change some implementation according to [this](https://github.com/908Inc/stickerpipe-chat-sample) documentation

Answer (score 0):

As per question you need private chat so you need to release private chat using below method when it will not require :

```
 public void release() {
        Log.w(TAG, "release private chat");
        privateChat.removeMessageListener(this);
        privateChatManager.removePrivateChatManagerListener(this);
    }
```

Here privateChatManager is initialize like

```
 privateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
```